# Is it possible to upgrade SonarQube 5.1.2 to 5.3?

Tags: sonarqube

I am interested in some improvements that SonarQube 5.3 brings. I am using 5.1.2 currently. 5.3 is not LTS I noticed on the website.

In my test environment I noticed that upgrade from 5.1.2 to 5.3 will fail.

Message in `/opt/sonarqube-5.3/logs/sonar.log` show database migration is not working.

How can I fix this?

```
2016.01.27 09:32:43 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] Starting DB Migration
2016.01.27 09:32:43 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  AddProjectLinksComponentUuid: migrating ===================================
2016.01.27 09:32:43 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- columns("project_links")
2016.01.27 09:32:43 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0100s
2016.01.27 09:32:43 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- add_column("project_links", "component_uuid", :string, {:limit=>50})
2016.01.27 09:32:43 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0370s
2016.01.27 09:32:43 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0 rows
2016.01.27 09:32:43 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  AddProjectLinksComponentUuid: migrated (0.0490s) ==========================
2016.01.27 09:32:43 INFO  web[DbMigration] 
2016.01.27 09:32:43 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  FeedProjectLinksComponentUuid: migrating ==================================
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[o.s.d.v.MassUpdate] 870 project links processed (14 items/sec)
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  FeedProjectLinksComponentUuid: migrated (0.1430s) =========================
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] 
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  RemoveProjectLinksProjectId: migrating ====================================
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- columns("project_links")
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0070s
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- remove_column("project_links", "project_id")
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0290s
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  RemoveProjectLinksProjectId: migrated (0.0360s) ===========================
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] 
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  AddEventsComponentUuid: migrating =========================================
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- columns("events")
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0060s
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- add_column("events", "component_uuid", :string, {:limit=>50})
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0260s
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0 rows
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- index_exists?("events", "component_uuid", {:name=>"events_component_uuid"})
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0040s
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- add_index("events", "component_uuid", {:name=>"events_component_uuid"})
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0180s
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0 rows
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  AddEventsComponentUuid: migrated (0.0590s) ================================
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] 
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  FeedEventsComponentUuid: migrating ========================================
2016.01.27 09:32:44 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator] Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.db.version.v52.FeedEventsComponentUuid
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error during processing of row: [uuid=208f1f81-5e64-4b35-8bfd-9a0bb53ce9a5,id=1829]
    at org.sonar.db.version.SelectImpl.newExceptionWithRowDetails(SelectImpl.java:89) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.SelectImpl.scroll(SelectImpl.java:81) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.MassUpdate.execute(MassUpdate.java:76) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.v52.FeedEventsComponentUuid.execute(FeedEventsComponentUuid.java:45) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.BaseDataChange.execute(BaseDataChange.java:45) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.DatabaseMigrator.executeMigration(DatabaseMigrator.java:95) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:455) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:316) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:61) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:198) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:81) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:303) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yieldSpecific(InterpretedBlock.java:229) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.WrapperMethod.call(WrapperMethod.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:206) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:567) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2595) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2227) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:356) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:213) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:217) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallSpecialArgBlockPassNode.interpret(CallSpecialArgBlockPassNode.java:66) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:198) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:224) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call.call(RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:202) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:198) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallNoArgBlockNode.java:32) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:357) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:312) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:142) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.eachCommon(RubyArray.java:1606) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(RubyArray.java:1613) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.call(RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:225) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:214) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:346) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:204) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallTwoArgNode.interpret(FCallTwoArgNode.java:38) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.WhenOneArgNode.whenNoTest(WhenOneArgNode.java:27) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.WhenOneArgNode.when(WhenOneArgNode.java:45) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CaseNode.interpret(CaseNode.java:132) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:198) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:164) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at RbCallUpgrade_2043231604.callUpgrade(RbCallUpgrade_2043231604.gen:13) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ruby.PlatformRubyBridge$1.trigger(PlatformRubyBridge.java:52) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.doUpgradeDb(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:130) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.doDatabaseMigration(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:112) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.access$000(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:37) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration$1.run(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:100) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executePreparedBatchAsMultiStatement(PreparedStatement.java:1446) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1277) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.sonar.db.version.UpsertImpl.addBatch(UpsertImpl.java:41) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.MassUpdate$1.handle(MassUpdate.java:80) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.version.SelectImpl.scroll(SelectImpl.java:78) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
    ... 159 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1911) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1203) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executePreparedBatchAsMultiStatement(PreparedStatement.java:1386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar:5.1.35]
    ... 165 common frames omitted
2016.01.27 09:32:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB migration failed | time=625ms
2016.01.27 09:32:44 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB Migration or container restart failed. Process ended with an exception
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StandardError) An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.db.version.v52.FeedEventsComponentUuid
vagrant@devops:/opt/sonarqube-5.3/logs$
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out this is caused by MySQL/MariaDB `binlog_format` setting. I changed this to `MIXED` in config file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
..
binlog_format       = MIXED
```

It seems that with SonarQube 5.3 this is required now. I didn't use this setting with 5.1.2